# lower bound for determinant of $(X^TY)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inner-products, upper-lower-bounds

Am looking for a lower bound for determinant, $\det(X^TY)$ where $X^T$ is $p \times n$ and $Y$ is $n \times p$. Is it $Tr(X^TY)^{-1}$? Regardless, what are other lower bounds for this? $X,Y$ are real-valued matrices.

Comment: What is $Z$ in this context?

Comment: sry, typo. changed it to $Y$

Comment: If $X = -cI$, $c>0$ and $Y=I$ when $c$ is negative and $n$ is odd then the $\det(X^T)$ will be $-c^n$ while $1/Tr(X^TY)$ will be $-1/(cn)$. For $c$ large enough the determinant would be arbitrarily smaller than the bound from the trace.

Comment: You might want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula

Comment: If $n < p$, then the determinant is always $0$, For $n \ge p$, the lower bound of the absolute value of the determinant is $0$. The lower bound for the determinant itself is $-\infty$. It is independent of the value of the trace for $p > 1$.